# Poll() to monitor a pin on BeagleBone Black. Continuous output even though pin not connected.

Tags: linux, interrupt, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I want to trigger an event whenever there is a rising edge on one of the pins of Beaglebone Black. 
Problem is, even though I havent connected that pin to anything, the output just goes on printing, interrupt occured, interrupt occured. I came across question [Interrupts in Beaglebone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831590/interrupts-in-beaglebone) 
on stackoverflow and tried to follow the steps. There was a link to a [Program](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Gpio-int-test.c) which implements the functionality. 
I read about poll() and I made slight changes in the program since I want to monitor just one pin. The changed code is :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
struct pollfd fdset[1];  // fdset[2] changed to fdset[1] since I will monitor just 1 pin
int nfds = 1;            // nfds changed from 2 to 1
int gpio_fd, timeout, rc;
char *buf[MAX_BUF];
unsigned int gpio;
int len;



if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: gpio-int <gpio-pin>\n\n");
    printf("Waits for a change in the GPIO pin voltage level or input on stdin\n");
    exit(-1);
}

gpio = atoi(argv[1]);

gpio_export(gpio);
gpio_set_dir(gpio, 0);
gpio_set_edge(gpio, "rising");
gpio_fd = gpio_fd_open(gpio);

timeout = POLL_TIMEOUT;

while (1) {
    memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));

    fdset[0].fd = gpio_fd;                 // This is the pin to be monitored
    fdset[0].events = POLLIN;

    //fdset[1].fd = gpio_fd;               // commented since I do not need this
    //fdset[1].events = POLLPRI;

    rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);      

    if (rc < 0) {
        printf("\npoll() failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (rc == 0) {
        printf(".");
    }

    if (fdset[0].revents & POLLIN) {
        len = read(fdset[0].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        printf("\npoll() GPIO %d interrupt occurred\n", gpio);
    }

            // ****Commented block****
    //if (fdset[0].revents & POLLIN) {
    //  (void)read(fdset[0].fd, buf, 1);
    //  printf("\npoll() stdin read 0x%2.2X\n", (unsigned int) buf[0]);
    //}

    fflush(stdout);
}

gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd);
return 0;
}
```

Running Angstrom on Beaglebone black.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt

> If the pin can be configured as interrupt-generating interrupt
>           and if it has been configured to generate interrupts (see the
>           description of "edge"), you can poll(2) on that file and
>           poll(2) will return whenever the interrupt was triggered. If
>           you use poll(2), set the events POLLPRI and POLLERR. If you
>           use select(2), set the file descriptor in exceptfds. After
>           poll(2) returns, either lseek(2) to the beginning of the sysfs
>           file and read the new value or close the file and re-open it
>           to read the value.

You have not set events POLLPRI and POLLERR.

```
struct pollfd fdset[1];
memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));
fdset[0].fd = fd;
fdset[0].events = POLLPRI | POLLERR;
...
poll()
...
lseek(fdset[0].fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
const ssize_t rc = read(fdset[0].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
```

The above works on a BeagleBone Black Rev. C running Debian with linux 3.8.13-bone47.

Answer (score 1):

Since you "havent connected that pin to anything", if it isn't internally tied low or high then it's just a floating input, which could cause the apparent interrupts you're seeing.

Comment: also, the example you cite uses POLPRI both when defining the pollfd.events and masking the received revents for the GPIO